# Kotlin How to reference correctly to the fasterxml class for the jacksonObjectMapper

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, import, build.gradle, fasterxml

[image: Screenshot with the error and my project hierachy]  **dependency snippet of my build.gradle File for the fasterxml class:**

```
dependencies {
    // Json
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.1"
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module', name: 'jackson-module-kotlin', version: '2.13.0'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two different libraries, so before all, first decide whether you want to use kotlinx-serialization or jackson.

For kotlinx you don't need the second dependency, but obviously you won't use the jackson mapper in your code but the one provided by kotlinx:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization#introduction-and-references

For jackson you need to include jackson-databind, not just the kotlin plugin (which just provides some extra kotlin-only features): `implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.0'`

Comment: Sadly, it did not change anything - I have been wondering, that pulling from a specific branch the source code and open it in IntelliJ will not make the code runnable although there are no errors in Remote Repository.